# Property 'hot' does not exist on type 'NodeModule'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a purchased react template with the following lines, but its not clear to me whats the purpose of this, the template its in JS and I want to change it to Typescript

The following lines were present in the template

```
 if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./dashApp.js', () => {
      const NextApp = require('./dashApp').default;
      ReactDOM.render(<NextApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
    });
  }
```

However when renamed to .TS, I get this error:

```
Property 'hot' does not exist on type 'NodeModule'.ts(2339)
```

What does this code really does? in plain english

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This code is related to Webpack's hot module replacement feature (HMR). `module.hot` works like this:

```
module.hot.accept(
  dependencies, // Either a string or an array of strings
  callback // Function to fire when the dependencies are updated
);
```

So the code you included does this: *when the code of `./dashApp.js` or one of the module it requires/imports in the requirement/import tree gets updated, re-render the whole React app.

The `hot` property on node modules it not standard, thus the TS error - make sure you install the required type definitions! `npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env` should do the trick.

---

Related reads:

- [Hot Module Replacement concept](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/): high-level Webpack doc on HMR
- [Hot Module Replacement API](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/) low-level Webpack doc on HMR, explaining how to use it and how does `module.hot.accept` does
- [Property 'hot' does not exist on type 'NodeModule'](https://github.com/vitaliy-bobrov/angular-hot-loader/issues/5): Github issue resolving the TS error

Comment: what about if I dont have webpack installed on the app? Basically I dont install it because it breaks my app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250509/cannot-read-property-thiscompilation-of-undefined-react-scripts-ts

Comment: Well, that above is webpack code. If you don't have Webpack installed, it won't run. Simple as that :)

Comment: It might also be necessary to add "webpack-env" to the "types" array in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 22):

Just to add to the accepted answer: After installing `@types/webpack-env` you might have to add `"types": ["webpack-env"]` to your `tsconfig.json` in `compilerOptions`. Only then it finally worked for me.

So your `tsconfig.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["webpack-env"]
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: This maybe because you added 'type'. By default all visible @types will be automatically added. See - https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types